# Enchanting glass armor removes my improvements

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just finished improving my glass chest piece to 90 armor vs 68 unimproved. When I went to enchant it with fortify health using a grand soul gem at dragon's reach and it shows me that once I enchant it the improvements will be remove setting it back to 61 armor. My smithing skill is at 73, light armor at 42, and enchanting at 74. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you on console or PC?  If PC, do you have all the patches (official and unofficial) installed?  I'm going to go ahead and answer, because I'm 99% sure what's going on (I just can't recall which patch fixed it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known display bug](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting#Bugs), where the enchanting table reads the item's base values instead of checking to see if the armor has been improved with the Smithing skill.  It does **not** actually lower the equipment's armor rating - complete the enchantment and view the finished item and you will see the armor is still as powerful as it was before being enchanted.  The preview simply shows the values as if the armor were unimproved.